# How solve row query with a lot of value, Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query

Tags: php

i have 67508 data row, and i have error like this,
how to solve this?

the error like this :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: IMSSP/-59
>
> Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines  to your php.ini.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
client_buffer_max_kb_size = '50240'
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 50240
```

Comment: Try this in your code
`ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); 
ini_set('sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize','524288'); 
ini_set('pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size','524288');`

Comment: it's working, but the only problem is my browser being not responding, do you have any suggestion to show 36000+ row, in select option?

Comment: Sorry, i don't get what do you mean by select option are you mean html select option.

Comment: Do pagination if your rows are too much it doesn't make sense to show it on one page.

Comment: yap, i mean HTML select option, so i get the value from database, but the row data have like 36000.data

Comment: how to make select option use pagination?

Comment: You know about pagination?

Comment: yeah, i know about pagination. but do you know about select option? in html?

Comment: why are you not using pagination?As far the select option is concern it can also be handle with that.

Comment: can you give me an example the code of select option using pagination?

Comment: pagination don't need select  option.

Comment: pagination don't need select  option.

Comment: i use select option for fill the form purpose.

Comment: I would suggest a auto complete select that limits the query, yes I've used this solution myself for selects that errored from memory